# Unable to install the app on iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios

I submitted app to App Store but it was rejected twice because they were unable to install the app on iPhone and iPad. They said the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on an iPhone and iPad.

They wrote that the next steps are:

> To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
>   key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your
>   app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device.
>   Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are
>   required and false if they must not be present on the device.

After first submit I removed completely UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key, but they still weren't able to install it.

I don't have iPhone or iPad, I tested app on simulators and it worked normally.

Here is my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Does anyone know how to modify it so that it can be installed on iPhones and iPads?

Comment: That's the only information they gave you ? "Unable to install" ?

Comment: @GIJOW Yes, that and that the problem is in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.

Comment: I think you need to find a way to test on a real device.

Answer (score 2):

This is from an Apple Engineer in November 2023. I used one of our Technical Support Incidents (TSIs) by choosing "Code Level Support" from developer.apple.com/account, therefore this response is as official as it can get.

We are using Xcode 15.0.1.

The Apple Engineer said it best so I will quote him.

> The only required value today is arm64 — iOS no longer supports armv7 devices. A brand new Xcode project today no longer includes the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities line in the Info.plist, instead deferring to the values found in the Xcode build setting INFOPLIST_KEY_UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, which by default are empty. With this configuration, Xcode will fill in the recommended default values. You can delete the existing entry in your Info.plist file (with its armv7 value) and defer to this approach.

> You should also ensure that the GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE build setting is enabled so that Xcode takes what remains from your existing Info.plist file, and then generates the final Info.plist file as one output during the build process. This is also a recommended default at this time, but may not be enabled for older projects.

Before the advice from the Apple Engineer, our previous values were:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
    <string>arm64</string>
</array>
```

According to our reading of [the latest docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities/), these 2 values were illogical. From that page:

> You typically use an array for the key’s associated value. The presence in that array of any of the above possible values indicates that the app requires the corresponding feature.

> Specify only the features that your app absolutely requires. If your app can accommodate missing features by avoiding the code paths that use those features, don’t include the corresponding key.

> For app updates, you can only maintain or relax capability requirements.

However, the Xcode > Organizer > *choose archive* > Validate App functionality did not complain. And for 2 years, the App Store review process did not complain, but suddenly and without warning, we too got the rejection:

> We were unable to install the app on iPad/iPhone. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on iPad/iPhone.

There are lots of SO questions with "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" but I chose to answer this one because it is the most general case and it specifies App Store rejection.

Comment: Nice. You could post comments to some of the other questions if you like, linking back here. I'd like to see this become the canonical statement of how this key works now; I had no idea that the optimal approach was to leave its value empty.

Answer (score 1):

`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` must be present in your Info.plist, as per [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html).

In all apps that I have on the App Store, this is what I have:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

so I'd suggest you try that.

Comment: Thank you, but I had exactly that inside first binary I submitted and they said they were unable to install the app on iPhone and iPad.. really strange.

Comment: My release build was approved by App Store after adding this. Saved the day, Thank you