# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities does not allow installing on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store

My app just got rejected by Apple with the message:

> We were unable to install the app on iPhone. The
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a
> way that the app will not install on iPhone.

A few things about the app:

1. I want it to run only on iPhone and not iPad. I don't enter this into `info.plist` manually but in XCode, I do select only iPhone. BTW, my XCode version is 12.4
2. I also set the orientation to portrait only in XCode
3. After the rejection, I changed the requirement to `arm64` from `armv7` so that it only installs on iPhone 6 or better
4. I also set the iOS target to version 11 in XCode.

With that said, does anyone see anything wrong with my new `info.plist` -- see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Ingrid TM</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>auth0</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your location is used to make sure you comply with your employer's policies when clocking in for work.</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: You should be aware that you cannot prevent the app from being installed on an iPad, it will just run in a iPhone-sized window.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this? My update got rejected for the same reason

Comment: It's been a while but if I recall correctly, the issue was not related to iPhone. Something was preventing the install process.

Comment: Other highly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034950/unable-to-install-the-app-on-iphone-and-ipad/77580062